# Export textbox text to .txt

Tags: c#

I'm trying to export the text from my textboxes to a .txt file. I found a few answers to this but I wasn't able to get this to work. Currently I have 5 textboxes that I want to export the data from. I want to have a standard format that will be easy to read.

Here's my current code:

```
private void totalaether_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   aefirstNum = (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) : 0;
   aesecondNum = (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox3.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) : 0;
   aethirdNum = (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text) : 0;
   aefourthNum = (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox5.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) : 0;

   op = "X";

   if (op == "X") total = (((aefirstNum * 3) * 3) * 3) + ((aesecondNum * 3) * 3) + (aethirdNum * 3) + aefourthNum;

   textBox6.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

So this is basically writing numbers to the textboxes. What I want to do is take those totals and output it to something like:

Brilliant: [number here]

Pure: [number here]

Greater: [number here]

Regular: [number here]

Total: [number here]

**Working Solution** This is including the `savefiledialog` and this allows me to set the text file name and choose save location.

```
        // set a default file name
        exportAether.FileName = ".txt";

        // set filters - this can be done in properties as well
        exportAether.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (exportAether.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(exportAether.FileName))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Brilliant: {0}", aefirstNum);
                writer.WriteLine("Pure: {0}", aesecondNum);
                writer.WriteLine("Greater: {0}", aethirdNum);
                writer.WriteLine("Regular: {0}", aefourthNum);
                writer.WriteLine("Total: {0}", total);
                // write other lines here
            }
```

**Thank you for the help this works great!**

Comment: Why do you have an `if` statement for a condition that will be - based on your current code - always true?

Comment: I have no clue. I'm new to programming and I saw it on a tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("filename.txt"))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Brilliant: {0}", aefirstNum);
    writer.WriteLine("Pure: {0}", aesecondNum);
    // write other lines here
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant, +1.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Now, is there a way to have this open a `savefiledialog` so I can choose the location and the filename?

Comment: That's the SaveFileDialog class. It's pretty easy to instantiate one, run ShowDialog on it, check the result for whether the user confirmed, and if so, that the `filename` property from it and plug that in as the filename. You should be able to find full documentation on the class in your help files or online via MSDN.

Comment: @Advancin: How about you give that a shot on your own and then post a separate question if you have trouble with it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now xD